# Tridion 9.1 deployer Worker Installing issue

Tags: sdl-tridion, deployer, sites-9

I am trying to install Tridion 9.1 Deployer as 2x Endpoints and 3x Workers. Deployer endpoint is running fine I can browse the `httpuplaod` but when I'm install Worker, getting below error. Any suggestion on this issue.

> 2020-02-20 13:21:30,659 ERROR [main] LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field storageSelector in
>   com.sdl.delivery.deployer.state.StepDataMapperFactory required a bean
>   of type 'com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.binarystorage.StorageSelector'
>   that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.binarystorage.StorageSelector' in your
>   configuration.
>
> 2020-02-20 13:21:30,662 ERROR [main] LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field storageSelector in
>   com.sdl.delivery.deployer.state.StepDataMapperFactory required a bean
>   of type 'com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.binarystorage.StorageSelector'
>   that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.binarystorage.StorageSelector' in your
>   configuration.
>
> 2020-02-20 13:21:30,671 ERROR [main] ServiceContainer - Could not
>   start ServiceContainer java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
>   null  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.sdl.delivery.service.ServiceContainer.main(ServiceContainer.java:92)
>     at
>   com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.start(WinServiceContainer.java:24)
>     at
>   com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.main(WinServiceContainer.java:41)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'stateMapperFactory': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'mapperFactory'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'stepDataMapperFactory': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'storageSelector'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.binarystorage.StorageSelector'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
>     ... 7 common frames omitted

Cd_storage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="11.1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <!--Optional:-->
    <!--
        Default Namespace Configuration
        The parameter to determine the default namespace
        'tcm' - Tridion Sites
    -->
    <Namespace default="${namespaceprefix:-tcm}"/>
    <Global>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ObjectCache Enabled="${objectcacheenabled:-false}">
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Policy Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy" Type="LRU">
                <!--
                    The maximum size of memory used by the cache. The string must consist a number
                    followed by units: "k" or "kb" for kilobytes; "m" or "mb" for megabytes (case insensitive)
                -->
                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="${cachesize:-16mb}"/>
            </Policy>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <!-- The Features element specifies classes that add additional functionality to the cache. -->
            <Features>
                <Feature Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker" Type="DependencyTracker"/>
            </Features>

        </ObjectCache>

        <Storages>

            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Id="defaultdb" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
                <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="10" Type="jdbc"/>
                <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost"/>
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433"/>
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker"/>
                    <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="xxxxx"/>
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>

        </Storages>
        <!--
            This configures the taxonomy reference count for keywords,
            if CountEnabled is set to False the reference count for keywords will not get updated.
            The default setting if this configuration is not present - keyword counts are enabled.
        -->
        <Taxonomies CountEnabled="${taxonomiescountenabled:-true}"/>
        <!--
            Configures transaction storage settings:
                 how long before a transaction gets rolled back (default is 600000 ms) and
                 interval to monitor for outstanding transactions (default is 5000ms).
        -->
        <Transaction MonitorInterval="${transactionmonitorinterval:-5000}" Timeout="${transactiontimeout:-600000}"/>
    </Global>
    <ItemTypes cached="false" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">

    </ItemTypes>
    <ConfigRepository CacheEnabled="true" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ClientId="registration" ClientSecret="${registrationpassword:-encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY=}" ConnectionTimeout="10000" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" ServiceUri="${discoveryurl:-http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc}" TokenServiceUrl="${tokenurl:-http://localhost:8082/token.svc}"/>
</Configuration>
```

Deployer config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Deployer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="11.1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/deployer-conf.xsd">
<Pipelines>
        <Pipeline Action="TridionBootstrap" Id="Tridion-Bootstrap" Verb="Content,Prepare,Commit,Rollback">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionUnzipStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Id="Tridion-Wait" Verb="Wait">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionWaitStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>

        <Pipeline Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Id="Tridion-ContentData-Deploy" Verb="Process">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionContentDataStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Id="Tridion-PreCommit-TX" Verb="PreCommit">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionPreCommitStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Id="Tridion-Commit-TX" Verb="Commit">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionCommitStep">
                    <RetryPoint PipelineId="Tridion-PreCommit-TX" StepId="TridionPreCommitStep"/>
                </Step>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Id="Tridion-Rollback-TX" Verb="Rollback">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionRollbackStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
        <Pipeline Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Finalize="true" Id="Tridion-Cleanup" Verb="*">
            <Steps>
                <Step Id="TridionCleanupStep"/>
            </Steps>
        </Pipeline>
    </Pipelines>

    <BinaryStorage Id="RedisStorage" Adapter="RedisBlobStorage">
        <Property Name="Host" Value="localhost"/>
        <Property Name="Port" Value="6379"/>
        <Property Name="Password" Value="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY="/>
        <Property Name="Timeout" Value="20000"/>
    </BinaryStorage>


    <State>
        <Storage Adapter="mssql" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" >
            <Property Name="host" Value="localhost"/>
            <Property Name="port" Value="1433"/>
            <Property Name="database" Value="Tridion_State_Store"/>
            <Property Name="user" Value="TridionStateStore"/>
            <Property Name="password" Value="xxxx"/>
        </Storage>
    </State>

    <Queues>

        <Queue Default="true" Verbs="Content" Adapter="JMS" Id="ContentQueue">

             <Property Name="Workers" Value="11"/> 
        </Queue>
        <Queue Verbs="Commit,Rollback" Adapter="JMS" Id="CommitQueue">

            <Property Name="Workers" Value="11"/>
        </Queue>
        <Queue Verbs="Prepare" Adapter="JMS" Id="PrepareQueue">

             <Property Name="Workers" Value="11"/> 
        </Queue>

        <Adapter Id="JMS">
            <Property Name="JMSConnectionFactoryBuilderClass"
                      Value="com.sdl.delivery.spring.configuration.jms.ActiveMQConnectionFactoryBuilder" />
            <Property Name="JMSUri" Value="http://localhost:8161/" />

            <Property Name="Username" Value="admin"/>
            <Property Name="Password" Value="admin"/>
        </Adapter>


        <Workers>
            <!-- Optional configuration properties -->
            <!--  <Property Name="QueuePollingInterval" Value="2s"/> -->
           <!--   <Property Name="RetriesInterval" Value="100ms"/> -->
           <!--  <Property Name="MaxRetries" Value="11"/> -->
           <!--   <Property Name="Cleanup" Value="true"/> -->
        </Workers>
    </Queues>

</Deployer>
```

Comment: Did you installed the Java on the Deployer server, looking at your log looking for Java.

Comment: Yes, I am installing deployer endpoint and worker on same machine , and deployer endpoint is already running so i dont think JAVA would be the issue.

Comment: My guess would be that you're missing some jars. Double/triple check the /lib folder (and the subfolders) from your deployer-worker.

Comment: I tried running this service directly from SDL installation media, not sure also, just in case anything is missing while copying the file to diff. location , but no luck.

Comment: Can somebody help me on this, or is it a known issue with Tridion sites 9.1 ?

Comment: Which deployer flavors did you use to install deployer-sites-worker or deployer-worker or deployer-dx-worker? Did you use add-on service and did you used any custom deployer-extension in the add-on service?

Answer (score 1):

Deployer-conf.xml is missing the Tridion-Process-Deploy and Undeploy steps.
Please go through the below lines which may help you out.

```
<Pipelines>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Bootstrap" Action="TridionBootstrap" Verb="Content,Prepare,Commit,Rollback">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionUnzipStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Wait" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Wait">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionWaitStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Process-Deploy" Action="Deploy" Verb="Process">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="SchemaDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy" Type="SchemaDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="PageDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy" Type="PageDeploy">
                    <Transformer Class="com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer"/>
                </Module>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="BinaryDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy" Type="BinaryDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="ComponentDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy" Type="ComponentDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="TemplateDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy" Type="TemplateDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="PublicationDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy" Type="PublicationDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="TaxonomyDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy" Type="TaxonomyDeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="ComponentPresentationDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy" Type="ComponentPresentationDeploy">
                    <Transformer Class="com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer"/>
                </Module>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="StructureGroupDeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy" Type="StructureGroupDeploy"/>
            </Step>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Process-Undeploy" Action="Undeploy" Verb="Process">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="PageUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageUndeploy" Type="PageUndeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="ComponentPresentationUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationUndeploy" Type="ComponentPresentationUndeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="TaxonomyUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyUndeploy" Type="TaxonomyUndeploy"/>
            </Step>
            <Step Id="StructureGroupUndeploy" Factory="com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory">
                <Module Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupUndeploy" Type="StructureGroupUndeploy"/>
            </Step>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-ContentData-Deploy" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Process">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionContentDataStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-PreCommit-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="PreCommit">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionPreCommitStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Commit-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Commit">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionCommitStep">
                <RetryPoint PipelineId="Tridion-PreCommit-TX" StepId="TridionPreCommitStep"/>
            </Step>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Id="Tridion-Rollback-TX" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="Rollback">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionRollbackStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>
    <Pipeline Finalize="true" Id="Tridion-Cleanup" Action="Deploy,Undeploy" Verb="*">
        <Steps>
            <Step Id="TridionCleanupStep"/>
        </Steps>
    </Pipeline>

</Pipelines>
```

Comment: No help :( . its same error after updating the config