# Can we have PCA GraphQL on WEB 8.5?

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, graphql, pca

We are currently on WEB 8.5 and maybe in sometime we migrate to Sites 9.x, "in a planning mode". What we liked the most about the Sites 9 is the GraphQL API, which we would like to access with WEB 8.5 also to feed all our applications WEB, MOBILE.

Now, My question is there a way we can have PCA with WEB 8.5. Any suggestion on this will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I did some PoC in the past on this topic, you can [read more](http://hem-kant.blogspot.com/2019/04/Hybrid-Architecture-SDL-WEB-8.5-and-SDL-Tridion-Sites-9.html) about this, and to answer your question YES, you can have PCA api working with WEB 8.5.

You need to follow below steps.

1. Create new Broker and state_store DB with Tridion Sites 9 DB scripts.
2. Install Sites 9 Discovery,Deployer and Content service.
3. Create new Topology Type and mappings and map them with BPT.

Comment: I find this a bit misleading answer. What you are saying is that you can combine a Sites 9 Content Delivery System with a Web 8.5 CM. This will technically work, indeed, but it is officially not supported by SDL.

Comment: Thanks Rick for the comment , All i wanted to know if this is possible "Technically", other than that, I have open question regarding the issue with 9.1 https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20733/tridion-9-1-deployer-worker-installing-issue

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK - and I can say officially it is not supported and tested, but I can’t think of anything which would break it. this is all unofficial

**Note:**

- As long as you don’t have SmartTarget in there, as in 8.5 SmartTarget was the Fredhopper version.
- From Sites 9.0 - officially we support CM's first upgrades.
- On the positive side, the java version on 8.5 and 11.0 is Java 8
- If your Implementation uses DXA then refer to [DXA and CIL are compatible](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000009093)

Always good to raise to SDL Support and get their feedback.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Velmurugan,  I have open question regarding the issue with 9.1 https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20733/tridion-9-1-deployer-worker-installing-issue, can you share some info on this.